# Parsing Plain Text Table

Tags: c#, regex, indexof

I'm trying to parse a table in plain text format. The program is written in Visual Studio using C#. I need to parse through the table and insert the data into the database.

Below is a sample table I will be reading in:

```
ID    Name          Value1        Value2         Value3       Value4  //header
1     nameA         3.0           0.2            2            6.2
2     nameB
3     nameC         2.9                          3.0          7.3
4     nameD         1.5           3.0            1.8          1.1
5     nameE
6     nameF      1.2        2.4          3.3           2.5
7     nameG      3.0        3.2          2.1           4.5
8     nameH                 88           12.4          28.9
```

In the example, I will need to capture data for id 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, and 8.

I thought of two ways to approach this, but neither of them works 100%.

**Method 1:**

By reading in the header, I can get the start index for each column. I will then use `Substring` collect data for each row.

*ISSUE:* once it past a certain row (which I will have no idea when this is happening), the columns shift, and `Substring` will no longer to collect the correct data.

This method will only collect correct data for 1, 3, and 4.

**Method 2:**

Using `Regex` to collect all the matches. I'm hoping this can collect ID, Name, Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, in this order.

My pattern is `(\d*?)\s\s\s+(.*?)\s\s\s+(\d*\.*\d*)\s\s\s+(\d*\.*\d*)\s\s\s+(\d*\.*\d*)\s\s\s+(\d*\.*\d*)`

*ISSUE:* data that are collected are shifted left for some rows. For example, on ID 3, `Value2` should be blank, but the regex will be reading `Value2 = 3.0`, `Value3 = 7.3`, and `Value4 = blank`. Same thing goes for ID 8.

**Question:**

How can I read in the whole table and parse them correctly?

(1) I do not know starting from which row the values will be shifted and

(2) I do not know how many cells it will be shifted by and if they are consistent.

**Additional Information**

The table is in a PDF file, I converted the PDF to text file so I can read in the data. The shifting data happens when a table goes across multiple pages, but it is not consistent.

**EDIT**

Below are some actual data:

```
68                        BENZYL ALCOHOL                               6.0                            0.4           1                  7.4

91                        EVERNIA PRUNASTRI (OAK MOSS)                 34                             3             3                  10

22                        test                                                                        2323          23                 12
```

Comment: can the values have whitespaces?

Comment: are there any spaces (' ') in the table? if not you can just read one line and split at all spaces and sort out all empty strings

Comment: @coolerfarmer thought the same - but does not work, cause there might be empty cells. So you do not know how to distribute 3 values on 4 columns. (Unless you build up some error-prone logic with counting the whitespaces in between to determine that.)

Comment: @dognose all data are separated by spaces(' '), and there could be whitespaces for both values and names. I'm only collecting the rows that has at least 1 value

Comment: @dognose for example, ID 3 and ID 8 both has empty cells, but I still want to collect data for other values.

Comment: Also, can the downvoter please explain why it's downvoted?

Comment: In my browser, the lines for ID 6 and ID 7 are messed up. For example, the 1.2 appears to be between the Name column and the Value1 column. Is this the way it really appears in the input?

Comment: @Mackenzie that is correct, it's not messed up, it's just how the text file look. Like I mentioned in the post, the shifting happens when the table goes across multiple pages in the pdf file.

Comment: Ok, I confused shifting with the empty cells. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Mackenzie Right, ID 6, 7 and 8 are all shifted. And ID 8 has an empty cell (for Value1)

Comment: @sora0419 I think there may be a way to do this, but it may be complicated to implement. The catch is to imagine the input as a 2-dimensional character array. Then, read each line from *Right*  to *Left*. Notice that the following condition holds. If a cell X in a column C[i] contains a value, then the start of X's textual representation is always to the right of the end of the column C[i - 1]'s header, even if shifting occurs.  At least that holds true, in the given example.

Comment: The [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class, which you can use from C# as well as from VB, is what you want to use for this. Search Stack Overflow for "TextFieldParser", and you'll find many examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, here u go! Use this regex pattern:

NOTE: you have to match this to any single line, not to the whole document! If you want to do it for your whole document then you have to add the 'multiline' modifier ('m'). You can do this by adding `(?m)` at the beginning of the regex pattern!

**EDIT:**

You provided some lines of your real data. Here's my updated regex pattern:

```
^(?<id>\d+)(?:\s{2,25})(?<name>.+?)(?:\s{2,45})(?<val1>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?(?:\s{2,33})(?<val2>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?(?:\s{2,14})(?<val3>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?(?:\s{2,19})(?<val4>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?$
```

Comment: thank you so much! I tried your regex and it works for the sample I provided, however, when I plug it in to the actual data, it does not work. This is one line from the actual data "68                        BENZYL ALCOHOL                               6.0                            0.4           1                  7.4", can you possibly explain why it's not capturing and help me modify it?

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Can You send me a few more lines of the data, so I can test it with them?

Comment: @sora I updated my post. Please report back if it works!

Comment: it works on the regex simulator I'm using, I'm pretty sure it'll work in my program as well, I'll implement it into my code. Thank you so much!

Comment: @sora I'll try optimizing the code! I'll report back!

Comment: @sora Now the code should work flawless. Make sure to use the new code (I replaced the old one in the edit)

Answer (score 1):

How about treating this file like a fixed-length file, where you can define each column by an index and length. Once you have defined your fixed length columns, you can just get the value for the column with `Substring`, then `Trim` to clean it up.

You can wrap all this up in a Linq statement to project to an anonymouse type and filter for the IDs you want.

Something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] select = new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 };
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("TextFile1.txt");

    var q = lines.Skip(1).Select(l => new {
        Id = Int32.Parse(GetValue(l, 0, 6)),
        Name = GetValue(l, 6, 11),
        Value1 = GetValue(l, 17, 11),
        Value2 = GetValue(l, 28, 13),
        Value3 = GetValue(l, 41, 14),
        Value4 = GetValue(l, 55, 13),
    }).Where(o => select.Contains(o.Id));

    var r = q.ToArray();        
}

static string GetValue(string line, int index, int length)
{
    string value = null;
    int lineLength = line.Length;

    // Take as much of the line as we can up to column length
    if(lineLength > index)            
        value = line.Substring(index, Math.Min(length, lineLength - index)).Trim();

    // Return null if we just have whitespace
    return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? null : value;
}
```